# my spring project runs on eclipse but when imported to intellij got error

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

my spring project runs on eclipse but when I import it on my intellij 16 got error

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/hostyourtournament-servlet.xml]

```
<servlet>
<description></description>
<servlet-name>hostyourtournament</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>hostyourtournament</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Error is self explanatory. Check if file exists in WEB-INF directory.

Comment: Yes it is.I tried using listener class also.But it didn't work

Comment: Hi, @xoxis. This is going to be a really tough question for anyone to answer because there's not a lot of information about *how* you're trying to run it in IntelliJ. Can you add additional information about what steps you took to import and run the project?